# send netcat output to cursor position

Tags: linux, bash, debian, netcat, caret

I have a device connected to the local network that sends a string to a specific port of a PC (connected to the same network) running Debian. On this PC I need to put that string to cursor position (for example, in an opened text editor).

I'm able to read the string from terminal with this command

```
nc -l -p 8888
```

but I can't figure out a way to put that string to cursor position.

After testing I would like this to become a service that remains active in the background

Thanks to anyone who has suggestions.

**EDIT:**

As suggested by JoseLinares i tried to copy the netcat output to the clipboard with the command

```
nc -l -p 8888 | xclip
```

Then i tried to paste it to a text editor, but nothing happen.
Using echo command (echo "something" | xclip) it works.

Another strange thing, if send output to a file (nc -l -p 8888 > test) and open that file with "nano" editor i see the value, but if i try to open it with "cat", it is empty.

Comment: Do you mean you wish to pipe the output of netcat to your shell but on the position your cursor is in?

Comment: Yes @JakeCope, exactly that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use xclip to save the output of nc in the clipboard:

```
nc -l -p 8888 | xclip
```

Then use xdotool to simulate a click in the middle button of the mouse. This will lead to copy the clipboard content in the cursor position in most desktop managers:

```
xdotool click 2
```

2 is the id of the middle button

Comment: thanks for the answer, the result of nc is not copied to the clipboard with xclip. If instead i try for example with   echo "test" | xclip   it works.

Comment: @MattiaGAZZANIGA and nc -l -p 8888 |& xclip ?

Comment: Not works also this way. I tried with nc -l -l 8888 | xclip -selection clipboard, but with no luck

Comment: @MattiaGAZZANIGA did you manage to do it? I can update the answer with your solution

Answer (score 0):

The `tcut cup` command, provided by `ncurses` allows you to move the terminal cursor to any position on the screen (0,0 being top-left).

You can use it this way for example:

```
nc -k -l 8888 \
| while read -r line; do
    tput cup 5 5
    printf '%s        ' "$line"
done
```

Here everything received by `nc` on port `8888` is written to the terminal at the position (5,5).

Note 1: There are several versions of `netcat` (`nc`). Yours may not have the `-k` switch (= don't die after the first connection has ended).

Note 2: You are mentioning a service. Services are generally not bound to a terminal, but you may open one (`man openvt`) or redirect the command above to an existing one (e.g. `> /dev/tty1`)

Comment: Thank you for the response, i will try your instructions. About the service, i doesn't need that start the terminal (I'm only using it now for testing), i just need that when i start up the PC, it will automatically listen to the 8888 port and send all the outputs to cursor position of the active user graphical session (that it will be an input field on a browser).

Comment: I'm afraid your program won't be able to know what is the currently active terminal in your current graphical session. On my machine, there are 40 pseudo-terminals currently running, and from the system point-of-view, they are all equally valid.